# 「該当記事へ課金したユーザのみ」が「該当記事を閲覧できる」ようにしたい時のDBテーブル構成について

Tags: php, mysql, データベース設計

**最終的にやりたいこと**
・「登録した任意ユーザ」がブログへ記事を投稿
・ブログ記事の一部を有料化
・「該当記事へ対して課金したユーザのみ」が「該当記事」を閲覧できるようにしたい

**現状のテーブル構成**
・ブログ記事テーブルb。u_idカラムあり
・ユーザテーブルu
※1対多

---

**分からないこと。判定フラグのDB格納**
「該当記事へアクセスしてきたユーザ」が、「該当記事へ課金したユーザ」かどうかの判定。
このような判定フラグをDBへ格納することは可能ですか？

**分からないこと。テーブル構成**
「該当記事へ課金したユーザ」であることをDBへINSERTするにはどうすれば良い？

- 案1.ブログ記事テーブルbにユーザ課金カラムを新規作成して、課金したユーザテーブルu_idを、「,」か何かで区切って複数格納していく
- 案2.ユーザテーブルuの1カラムに、課金したブログ記事テーブルb_idを、「,」か何かで区切って複数格納していく
- 案3.「課金テーブルk」を新規作成して、「ブログ記事テーブルb_id」と「ユーザテーブルu_id」を格納していく
  ※この時の三者の関係性は、「ブログ記事テーブルb」と「ユーザテーブルu」と「課金テーブルk」がそれぞれ「多対多」？

その他の案は何かありますか？

**補足**
ブログはWordPressなどの一般的なものではありません

Comment: 箇条書きを多用する傾向にありますが、使いどころをピンポイントに抑えた方が見やすくなると思います。 / 「複数の質問や案」だけでなく「ただの文章」にも`・`が使われているので、結局候補のリストがいくつあるのかパッと見で分かりづらくなります。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mysqlのタグがあるのでRDBMSとすれば、案1・案2は基本的に避けて、案3を選択してください。

> ※この時の三者の関係性は、「ブログ記事テーブルb」と「ユーザテーブルu」と「課金テーブルk」がそれぞれ「多対多」？

いいえ。

`ブログ記事`と`ユーザ`の関係が多対多であり、それを実現するのが`課金テーブルk`です。
これを「中間テーブル」と言ったりします。

> ・このような判定フラグをDBへ格納することは可能ですか？

に対する回答としては、`課金テーブルk`のレコード有無で判断すれば良いでしょう。
要件によっては有効期限を持たせたり、無効化するフラグを持つ設計もアリだと思います。