# <video src="blob:https://xxxx"></video>の動画はどこにありますか？

Tags: javascript, 動画

例えば[リンク先](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20190731/k10012014821000.html)の該当箇所は下記だと思うのですが、

```
<video preload="none" webkit-playsinline="null" playsinline="null" src="blob:https://www3.nhk.or.jp/2ef5ce19-8e1b-476e-bf2c-b1583ca31a63"></video>
```

---

**Q1.この動画はどこにありますか？**
そもそも動画URLを探し出すことは可能ですか？

**Q2.ブラウザに「blob:https://www3.nhk.or.jp/2ef5ce19-8e1b-476e-bf2c-b1583ca31a63」と入力すると、「ファイルが見つかりませんでした」と表示されるのはなぜですか？**
生のバイナリデータが表示されるわけではない？？

**Q3.ブラウザに「https://www3.nhk.or.jp/2ef5ce19-8e1b-476e-bf2c-b1583ca31a63」と入力すると、「エラー ページを表示できませんでした。」と表示されるのはなぜですか？**

- 404エラーですか？
- それともファイルは存在するけれどもサイト側が意図的にエラーを返しているのですか(と推測されますか)？

Comment: 質問をまとめているようで、結局聞きたいことが何なのか分かりにくい質問が多いです。改善してください。

Comment: SOでの投稿は「一問一答」が理想なので、複数の質問が含まれるような書き方は回答のハードルを上げてしまう印象です。 / [過去にもコメントしました](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/55690/#comment59815_55690)が、箇条書きに頼らず、会話的なトーンでの投稿を心がけてみてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1.についてだけ。

ブラウザのDevToolsなどで確認してください。

動画はiframeで下記URLを挿入しています。
https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20190731/movie/k10012014821_201907310540_201907310546.html

リクエストを見るにakamaihd.netからmp4を分割したファイルを取得しているようです。別の回答でもご指摘の通りツールでも介さないと再生できないと思われます。
`https://nhks-vh.akamaihd.net/i/news/k10012014821_201907310540_201907310546.mp4/segment29_0_av.ts`

Comment: 「リクエストを見るにakamaihd.netから」これはどうやって確認したのですか？ どこへリクエストを投げているか、はコードのどの部分から判断できますか？

Comment: DevToolsのネットワークタブを見てください。

Comment: ネットワークタブで確認できたのですが、ソースコードで確認できないですか？　iframeに記載されているjsでakamaihdを検索したのですが、見つかりませんでした。サーバからリクエストを投げている、ということですか？

Comment: ネットワークタブの該当行のinitiator列を見れば、何からのリクエストが分かります。ブラウザからの通信ですから"サーバーからのリクエスト"ということはありえません。これ以上は代わりにソース読んでくれ、の別質問を立てられては。

Comment: 「ブラウザからの通信ですから"サーバーからのリクエスト"ということはありえません」。なるほど、それでは探してみたいと思います

Answer (score 3):

[`URL.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)で生成された`blob:`スキーマのURLです。それを生成したページ内部でのみ有効なURLであり、ブラウザのアドレスバーで使うことはできません。また、サーバ上のリソースのパスを表現しているわけではなく、ブラウザのメモリ内の何かを指しています。

何かしら外部のリソースからblob URLの動画を作っているのでしょうから、該当ページのコードをよく読めば元の動画がどこから来るのか知ることはできるかもしれません。しかしながら、blob URLを使っているくらいなので直接再生できるような形式で元の動画を置いている可能性は低いと思います。